# How to interact with iPhone browser without touching it?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, bluetooth

So, I am developing this VR website online with JavaScript. 
I have a function that instantiates an object in the 3D room, at the given location that the user is "watching".

However, I don't see how I can execute that function when my iPhone is locked away in the VR headset. I have been thinking about volumeup-button on my headset that is connected to it or something, but haven't found anyone that has done that before.

Do you guys have any advice? Could there be a way of connecting a BlueTooth remote to it? Or is it simply impossible?

TLDR; How to execute a function in the browser on your phone, when you can't touch your phone.

Answer (score 0):

It is [possible to connect Bluetooth keyboard](http://ioshacker.com/how-to/connect-iphone-or-ipad-to-a-bluetooth-keyboard) to iOS devices, as you suggested in your post.

You might also leverage the other sensors in the phone (such as accelerometer, gyroscope, microphone), but I'm not certain if Safari has access to those.  You would have more options if you developed a standalone application rather than trying to go through a browser.